# Understand javascript variable scope with a test

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I am trying to test Map class. My class has a method getCenter() that returns {x:0,y:0}. Also, I want to get {x:1,y:0} calling getRight() and I still want that getCenter() returns {x:0,y:0}.

```
var assert = require('assert')
    , Map = require('../lib/map')

describe('Map()', function () {
    describe('#getCenter()', function () {
        it('should return [0,0] by default', function () {
            var map = new Map()
            assert.deepEqual({x: 0, y: 0}, map.getCenter())
        })
    })
    describe('#getRight()', function () {
        it('should return [1,0] by default', function () {
            var map = new Map()
            assert.equal(1, map.getRight().x)
            assert.deepEqual({x: 0, y: 0}, map.getCenter())
        })
    })
})
```

But I am doing something wrong:

```
var Map = function () {
    this.center = {x: 0, y: 0}
}

module.exports = Map

Map.prototype.getCenter = function () {
    return this.center
}

Map.prototype.getRight = function () {
    var new_position = this.center
    new_position.x += 1
    return new_position
}
```

I dont want to alter this.center. How can I create new variable? I dont understand the scope of "this.center". I am not changing that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because javascript is based on C and is crazy, assigning a variable to an object actually sets it as a pointer to that object (this also applies to arrays, which is why you need to call `var b = a.splice()`. So, you'll need to either clone the object (which is bloody difficult to do well: [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)) or set the new variable to the property directly:

`return {x: this.center.x + 1, y: this.center.y}`

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a copy, instead of just making a reference. Objects and arrays are passed by reference in JS.

```
var new_position = {x:this.center.x,y:this.center.y};
```

Comment: or just `return {x:this.center.x + 1, y:this.center.y};`